# Debugger runs only once per IDE startup

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, debugging, mstest

I have been using MS VS2010 debugger for quite some time now and didn't came across any problems until today.

As a tester I start my debugger in testing mode (single test debugging) right after loading the project and it starts a whole batch of tests written.

**Despite starting all the tests the debugger itself works properly**.

I stop proceeding in >Test Results< view, put the caret again in body of testing method and rerun the debugger.

The result is > Not executed < with an very simple error:
"Failed to queue test run 'myLogin@myMachine date': Unable to start debugging."

I've gone through similar questions here so I can give some clues for those, who has any idea what is going on:

- problem appeared today
- i haven't mess with any .dll's that are outside my project
- there is no hanging process noticable in Windows Task Manager
- source catalog of an assembly is trusted
- only closing and starting VS again helps; reloading project, changing project does't 'solve' the problem
- i debug mostly my tests (and methods they call), but debugging main application act in the same way
- building / executing project works fine

I hope it will be easy for you to point an error out.

Comment: Look for a better diagnostic message in the Output window.

Comment: @Daniel, 
Project's type is 'Test Project' for C#

Comment: @Hans,
Don't really know if you're asking for any specific information, so  whole output here: http://wklej.to/ITsJ

Comment: Is something wrong with the question or just there is no person having idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and this helped me:

http://blogs.webguild.com/gary/archive/2010/08/06/how-i-solved-the-vs2010-error-quotunable-to-start-debugginghellipquot.aspx